# Formularios Web con Python

Tags: python, formularios, flask

Me ha pedido que automatice una carga de unos registros en una base de datos SQL, con `id, cedula, departamento y tipo de pago` con Python.

He investigado y he encontrado un framework llamado Flask, en apariencia es mas simple, pero no he logrado de hacerlo como los formularios de Google.

Comment: Hola Bryan.  Has de mostrar lo que has intentado y por que no te funcionó. Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas te propongo que uses algo como esto:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import web
from web import form

urls = ('/', 'ingreso')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

# Creamos nustro formulario:
login = form.Form(form.Textbox('usuario'),form.Password('clave'),form.Button('Iniciar'))

class ingreso:
    def GET(self):
        f = login()
        return f.render()

def main():
    app.run()
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Esto te ofrece una salida como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es bastante sencillo de usar y entender. [Aquí](https://jolthgs.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/desarrollo-web-con-python-y-web-py/) te dejo un enlace a un mini-tutorial muy completo de ello. Espero que sirva.

Comment: Gracias, la verdad es muy sencillo, ahora puedo tomar los datos mejor para unirlos a la base de datos SQL. He verificado la pagina, esta de lujo.

Comment: Perfecto, si te sirvió la respuesta indícalo para cuando alguien visite esta pregunta con el mismo problema o similar. Saludos